# Django: Querying read-only view with no primary key

Tags: django, django-models

```
class dbview(models.Model):
    # field definitions omitted for brevity
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'read_only_view'

def main(request):
    result = dbview.objects.all()
```

Caught an exception while rendering: (1054, "Unknown column 'read_only_view.**id**' in 'field list'")

There is **no primary key** I can see in the view. Is there a workaround?

Comment:
I have no control over the view I am accessing with Django. MySQL browser shows columns there but no primary key.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you say 'I have no control over the view I am accessing with Django. MySQL browser shows columns there but no primary key.'

I assume you mean that this is a legacy table and you are not allowed to add or change columns?

If so and there really isn't a primary key (even a string or non-int column*) then the table hasn't been set up very well and performance might well stink.

It doesn't matter to you though. All you need is a column that is guaranteed to be unique for every row. Set that to be 'primary_key = True in your model and Django will be happy.

- There is one other possibility that would be problemmatic. If there is no column that is guaranteed to be unique then the table might be using composite primary keys. That is - it is specifying that two columns taken together will provide a unique primary key. This is perfectly valid relational modelling but unfortunatly unsupported by Django. In that case you can't do much besides raw SQL unless you can get another column added.

Comment: Very helpful.  One thing to add; if the column you want to use for a primary key is a CHAR type, it can't be longer than 255 characters.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question, which pertains to a db view, not a table. You have specify one of your fields as a pk for django, whether it is or not.  You can get away with this since there will never be any insert/update on the relation via the ORM. See [the answer from David S](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11594959/519015) and my comment thereon for more about this technique.

Answer (score 17):

I have this issue all the time.  I have a view that I can't or don't want to change, but I want to have a page to display composite information (maybe in the admin section).  I just override the save and raise a NotImplementedError:

```
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

(although this is probably not needed in most cases, but it makes me feel a bit better)

I also set managed to False in the Meta class.

```
    class Meta:
       managed = False
```

Then I just pick any field and tag it as the primary key.  It doesn't matter if it's really unique with you are just doing filters for displaying information on a page, etc.

Seems to work fine for me.  Please commment if there are any problems with this technique that I'm overlooking.

Comment: You can tag a non-unique field as primary key for read-only access, but this has ramifications for things like `queryset.distinct().count()` and instance comparisons.  As a workaround for the latter, you can redefine `__eq__()` on the model.

Comment: Something you can do to the view if you want to have an id is use the `row_number()` function (at least in PostgreSQL).  `SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY field ASC) AS id,`

Answer (score 3):

If there really is *no primary key* in the view, then there is no workaround.

[Django requires each model to have exactly one field `primary_key=True`.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id1)

Comment: Thank you! If I cannot see primary key in the view it means that there is no primary key...? Guess I'll just revert to raw SQL.

Comment: Not necessarily. See my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

There should have been an auto-generated `id` field when you ran `syncdb` (if there is no primary key defined in your model, then Django will insert an `AutoField` for you).

This error means that Django is asking your database for the `id` field, but none exists. Can you run `django manage.py dbshell` and then `DESCRIBE read_only_view;` and post the result? This will show all of the columns that are in the database.

Alternatively, can you include the model definition you excluded? (and confirm that you haven't altered the model definition since you ran `syncdb`?)

Comment: Thanks, I should have made it more clear in the beginning. Please see the update.

Comment: I'm not asking to see the row you are accessing, I just want to see your model definition (not the same thing).

Comment: The model definitions are like this: text = models.CharField()  However, I cannot define a field with 'primary_key=True' because the view does not seem to have a primary key.

Comment: Sorry to be so blunt, but do you know what a primary key is?

Comment: The way I see the problem: the view does not have a primary key (I can't see it), Django requires each model to have a primary key (either manually defined by 'primary_key=True' or default 'id' if not defined by user).

Comment: No matter if I define a primary key in my model or skip this, Django will still require a primary key to be in a view I am trying to query...

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is over a decade old, but I ran into this recently and came to SO looking for a good answer. I had to come up with a solution that addresses the OP's original question, and, additionally, allows for us to add new objects to the model for unit testing purposes, which is a problem I still had with all of the provided solutions.

main.py

```python
from django.db import models

def in_unit_test_mode():
    """some code to detect if you're running unit tests with a temp SQLite DB, like..."""
    import sys
    return "test" in sys.argv
    """You wouldn't want to actually implement it with the import inside here. We have a setting in our django.conf.settings that tests to see if we're running unit tests when the project starts."""

class AbstractReadOnlyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta(object):
        abstract = True
        managed = in_unit_test_mode()

    """This is just to help you fail fast in case a new developer, or future you, doesn't realize this is a database view and not an actual table and tries to update it."""
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not in_unit_test_mode():
            raise NotImplementedError(
                "This is a read only model.  We shouldn't be writing "
                "to the {0} table.".format(self.__class__.__name__)
            )
        else:
            super(AbstractReadOnlyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class DbViewBaseModel(AbstractReadOnlyModel):
    not_actually_unique_field = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    # the rest of your field definitions

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'read_only_view'

if in_unit_test_mode():
    class DbView(DbViewBaseModel):
        not_actually_unique_field = IntegerField()
        """This line removes the primary key property from the 'not_actually_unique_field' when running unit tests, so Django will create an AutoField named 'id' on the table it creates in the temp DB that it creates for running unit tests."""
else:
    class DbView(DbViewBaseModel):
        pass

class MainClass(object):
    @staticmethod
    def main_method(request):
        return DbView.objects.all()
```

test.py

```python
from django.test import TestCase
from main import DbView
from main import MainClass

class TestMain(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.object_in_view = DbView.objects.create(
            """Enter fields here to create test data you expect to be returned from your method."""
        )
    
    def testMain(self):
        objects_from_view = MainClass.main_method()
        returned_ids = [object.id for object in objects_from_view]
        self.assertIn(self.object_in_view.id, returned_ids)
```