# Django model with only foreign keys

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I have an existing database, which cannot be changed.

It contains three tables:

```
A:
  a_id [primary key]

B:
  b_id [primary key]

A_B:
  a_id [foreign key]
  b_id [foreign key]
```

I want to create django models for these tables. Since django requires each model to have one primary key, model for the `A_B` table will have autogenerated primary key, eg. `A_B_id`. This is a problem, because the database schema cannot be changed.

Is it possible in django to use tables which have only foreign keys?
How could this problem be solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Querying read-only view with no primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605896/django-querying-read-only-view-with-no-primary-key)

Comment: According to the 8 years old accepted answer on that question, composite keys are "unsupported by Django". That was eight years ago, so things might have changed. Another answer suggests making any unique column as primary key. I cannot do that, because the table has only two columns -- both foreign keys, which cannot be primary keys in django. Although that question and its answers and comments do partly answer my question, I would prefer to keep this question open, since all discussion on the other one is quite old and there may be a new answer to the question.

Comment: I tried with a ManyToManyField (for A_B table) but even for these tables Django creates an id field.

Comment: There have been multiple attempts to implement composite (primary) keys, but none of them have been successful thus far. I'm afraid Django still doesn't have an adequate solution.

Comment: Yes, it's impossible to do right now, even with manually modifying migrations files.